# How to return result of Prime factor Algroithm containing for Loops?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I’ve recently been given a practice problem from a tuition book called “jumping into c++” and have this task here:

> Design a program that finds all numbers from 1 to 1000 whose prime factors, when added together, sum up to a prime number (for example, 12 has prime factors of 2, 2, and 3, which sum to 7, which is prime). Implement the code for that algorithm. (Hint: If you don’t know the algorithm to find the prime factors of a number and have trouble figuring it out, it’s OK to look it up on Google! I meant it when I told you that you don’t need to know math to be a programmer.)

I came across an algorithm online that does serve its purpose and returns all factors of a number by dividing by two whilst being run through a modulus operator to test if its divisible. However when it checks what value ABOVE 2 can divide the input number between 1-1000, for example 9 (having the prime factors 3,3) the algorithm uses a for loop to divide the number and return the factors. So how would I go about recording this value to add to a total variable and return that value to print.

Here’s the algorithm I’m using[1]:

```
// Program to print all prime factors and add factors to print total
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h> 
using namespace std; 

// Function Prototype
void primeFactors(int n); 

/* Driver program to test above function */
int main() 
{ 
    for(int i=2;i<=10;i++)
    {
        cout << i << " : ";
        primeFactors(i); 
    }

    return 0;
} 

// A function to print all prime factors of a given number n 
void primeFactors(int n) 
{ 
    //Declare Total Variable
    int totalPrime = 0;

    // Print the number of 2s that divide n 
    while (n%2 == 0) 
    { 
        totalPrime = totalPrime + 2;
        cout << "2 "; 
        n = n/2; 
    } 

    // n must be odd at this point. So we can skip 
    // one element (Note i = i +2) 
    for (int i = 3; i <= sqrt(n); i = i+2) 
    { 
        // While i divides n, print i and divide n 
        while (n%i == 0) 
        { 
            cout << i << " "; 
            n = n/i; 
        } 
    } 

    // This condition is to handle the case when n 
    // is a prime number greater than 2 
    if (n > 2)
    {
        totalPrime = totalPrime + n;
        cout << n << " "; 
    }
    //Format and Output the cumulative values of prime factors and a new line
    cout << " = " << totalPrime << endl;    
}
```

As you can see, I've tried declaring a variable named total at the start of the function and add the value 2 after the while(n%2==0) and by n after the if(n > 2) statement however, when a number, like 9 arose in the program, because the use of an if statement in the algorithm, it would only add to the total of numbers that factors were not of the same value above 2.

Therefore, you'd get this on output:

```
2 : 2 = 2
3 : 3 = 3
4 : 2 2 = 4
5 : 5 = 5
6 : 2 3  = 5
7 : 7  = 7
8 : 2 2 2  = 6
9 : 3 3  = 0
10 : 2 5  = 7
```

I contemplated adding the add total inside the for loop however it's out of scope I believe so changing the value inside it won't alter the output and would keep the variable at it's already defined value.

How would I therefore work out the total sum of the prime factors when added up after being worked out from a number if the calculated factor is in a for loop?

[1] Algorithm sourced from: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-prime-factors-of-a-given-number/

Comment: not really clear what you want to count. You should also add the desired output

Comment: instead of `std::cout`  them, store them in container (`std::vector<int> primes;`, `primes.push_back(i)`) and return that container.

Comment: you want to sum the primefactors? or sum all possible factors?

Comment: As the practice problem says; I need to sum all the prime factors of one number then test if it's prime but I'm just working out sum first before running a isPrime function to test it.

Comment: dont mix i/o and computations. Make your function return a `std::vector` of the prime factors. hint: you dont need a `isPrime` unless you aim for maximum efficiency, your `primeFactors` is all you need (once you make it return the factors)

Comment: Hmm I'll look into Vectors right now as they haven't been mentioned in the book as of now, but the following chapters discuss data storage and manipulations so it's more or likely going to show up at some point especially seeing as my next chapter is arrays.

Answer (score 0):

you should add inside this loop to totalPrime Varaiable

```
for (int i = 3; i <= sqrt(n); i = i+2) 
{ 
    // While i divides n, print i and divide n 
    while (n%i == 0) 
    { 
        cout << i << " ";
        //add to sum 
        totalPrime = totalPrime + i;
        n = n/i; 
    } 
}
```